# SSRS report allow to external user

Tags: reporting-services, external, onavailable

I have to make avaible same reports so external users.

Is it possible? If yes what I have to do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try changing setting the `SendEmailToUserAlias` property to False in rsreportserver.config, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver16). By default this value will be set to True, which means users can only assign subscriptions to their own user accounts (the "To" setting will be greyed out).

You should also add a relevant value for `DefaultHostName`.